# ffmpeg микширование видео потоков

Tags: c++, c, видео, ffmpeg

Стоит задача к аудио-конференции(уже существующей и настроенной) добавить видео.

Микширование аудио для нескольких источников реализовано через функционал ffmpeg.
Видео будет приходить через другие порты, отдельные от аудио и, значит, его можно микшировать независимо от аудио.

Интересуют материалы/ссылки на документацию и **примеры** по декодированию, кодированию, склейке видео(картинок покадрово) для ffmpeg на с/c++.

Comment: [Основная документация](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) не подходит, там вроде все на C

Comment: @Yaroslav нет, там про видео - только ключи для командной строки

Comment: - [такое начальное руководство](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg)  Подходит ?

Comment: @Yaroslav это я видел, там только декодирование видео. И открытие формата и кодека из существующего файла. У меня RTP потоки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я работаю с RTSP потоком там открытие такое же, как обычного файла

```
AVFormatContext * format_context;
AVCodecContext * codec_context;
AVCodec * codec;
AVDictionary *optionsDict = NULL;


av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
avformat_open_input(&format_context,"rtsp://192.168.1.51:554/av0_0", NULL, NULL);
 /*поиск инфрормации в потоке*/
avformat_find_stream_info(format_context, NULL);
number = -1;
for(i = 0;i < format_context->nb_streams;i++){
  if(format_context->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
    number = i;
    break;
  }
}
if(number == -1){
 return FAILURE; // Didn't find a video stream
}
codec_context = format_context->streams[vs->number]->codec;
codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_context->codec_id);
if(codec == NULL) {
    return FAILURE; // Codec not found
}

rc = avcodec_open2(codec_context,codec,&optionsDict);
if(rc < 0){
    return FAILURE;
}
```

А дальше с этим `context` работаешь как с обычным файлом. Все тоже самое. 
Кодировани/декодирование все делает ffmpeg

А в этой структуре `struct SwsContext * sws_context;`  лежит изображение в формате RGB с ним можно работать как угодно. Но для работы с изображением нужна другая библиотека. Можно [gdk-pixbuf](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/) а можно и [cairo](https://www.cairographics.org/documentation/)

Comment: О, спасибо. А склейку видео изображений уже надо как-то иначе организовывать, не через ffmpeg?

Comment: да, накладывать изображения и рисовать на изображении нужно используя другие библиотеки

Answer (score -2):

Выбросить ваш настроенный велосипед, взять [openMCU-ru](http://openmcu.ru/) и не тратить время.